# How to implement Database content in .xml and present it in a listview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to create an app that will have a listview in it when clicking each listview will open an .xml file containing data and images stored into database.
I just want to know how to implement them into .xml and present into listview.
Thankyou

Comment: Can you explain more? Is the problem about showing the listview or about showing data and images after a list item is clicked in listview

Comment: The problem is about showing the data and images after a list item is clicked in a seperate .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to create another activity which inflate your xml which contain ImageView and more.and then pass id as intent and access content from database using id.and set image in imageview accordingly. This link may help you

http://yournextleap.blogspot.in/2012/02/insert-image-to-database-and-display.html

Comment: It depends on the kind of view to be shown in the activity. It can be as simple as a Linear layout consisting of a text view and a image view. Please provide some visual design

Comment: first question is unclear so what i understand from question. i just give solution accordingly now it's totally depends upon user how to design and implements.

Comment: My .xml will have and image view and 4-5 text views thats all

Comment: Create a linear layout with vertical orientation. It will contain 1 imageview and 5 textviews